# How to use FastText embeddings in a NetGraph?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Does Mathematica 11 have access with either the Wikipedia or CommonCrawl [FastText](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText) embeddings? Maybe this is built-in through the Neural Net Repository or available through a `NetEncoder`?

Comment: I'm not sure this is currently possible... But there are many other embeddings you can use in the neural net repo, at least. It does seem like the format of the [pre-built models](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html) is relatively parseable so you may be able to use them that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download and extract the [data](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html).

```
f = OpenRead["wiki-news-300d-1M.vec"];
```

The first line of the file contains the number of words in the vocabulary and the size of the vectors.

```
{n, d} = Read[f, {Number, Number}]
```

> {999994, 300}

```
t = Table[Read[f, Join[{Word}, ConstantArray[Real, d]]], {10(*n*)}];
tokens = t[[;; , 1]];
emb = t[[;; , 2 ;;]];
```

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171569

```
net = NetChain[
  {
   EmbeddingLayer["Weights" -> Append[emb, ConstantArray[0, d]]],
   LongShortTermMemoryLayer[10],
   SequenceLastLayer[],
   2,
   SoftmaxLayer[]
   },
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Tokens", tokens}],
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]
  ]
```

[image]